# free or cheap Email hosting service for up to 10 users for custom domain

Tags: web-hosting, email

Considering Google Apps is no longer free as of recently, are there any similar services? I know of Zoho Mail, which is free for up to 3 users.  However, I don't like their interface.  If not free, any very cheap services which one can recommend?

Comment: @JohnConde - why is the question closed?  For example, the user who replied below perfectly answered my question and I'm sure other users will find this relevant.

Comment: It's a shopping question which are not on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using Microsoft? Here's an article describing how to set it up if you're interested.

http://www.labnol.org/internet/setup-outlook-on-custom-domain/24699/

https://domains.live.com/

Comment: Somehow had no idea Microsoft where offering this service! Free up to 500-accounts, and unlimited storage - perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Glad this solution worked for you :)